# Signing a large file with Ardor Account

Tags: ardor

I want to sign a file (a picture of 1.4 Mb) with my Ardor Account, in order to have a timestamped proof of ownership.
I tried the generateFileToken API, but it seems to work just with smaller files (no more than 40 kb).
How could I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to increase the max file upload size of your node using the nxt.maxUploadFileSize property in nxt.properties.

For example, set:

```
nxt.maxUploadFileSize=10000000
```

To set the limit to 10MB